# Trying to work through this closure example...?

Tags: javascript, function, closures

```
var o = Object.create({inherited: 1}, {
foo: {
  get: (function () { // a closure
      var closured = 'foo';
      return function () {
        return closured+'bar';
      };
    })()
  }
});

o.foo; // "foobar"
```

I'm having some issues with this. I don't really understand how we're getting the string `"foobar"` as a result. I'll write my current erroneous understanding of this code, and hopefully someone can explain where I'm mistaken.

1. `o` is an object with the property `foo`.
2. `foo` corresponds to an object with one property, `get`. (This seems to be mistaken but I can't see how.)
3. `get` corresponds to self-invoking anonymous function that returns a function consisting of the one line `return closured+'bar';`

That being said, I would expect `o.foo` to return an object, and `o.foo.get` to return a function, and `o.foo.get()` to return `"foobar"`.

But that's not what's happening, and I don't know why.

Also, separately, why would you ever write something this way? Why write:

```
get: (function () { // a closure
      var closured = 'foo';
      return function () {
        return closured+'bar';
      };
    })()
```

Instead of simply:

```
get: (function () { // a closure
      var closured = 'foo';
        return closured+'bar';
    })()
```

What good is done by the extra function layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to `Object.create` should be a properties descriptor object. That is an object that describes the properties to be added to the prototype—not literally the object itself. For example:

```
var o = Object.create({inherited: 1}, {
   foo: { /* ... property descriptor object ... */ },
   bar: { /* ... property descriptor object ... */ }
});
```

In the above example we are adding two properties to the prototype of the new object: `foo` and `bar`. Each of those properties can be configured in various ways using the  descriptor object.

The descriptor object accepts several configuration properties, namely: `configurable`, `enumerable`, `value`, `writable`, `get`, `set`.

In your original example, you effectively configured a getter function for the property `foo`. If you wish to simply set the value of the property `foo`, then instead you must create a `value` property inside the descriptor and add your intended value there (be it actually an object with a property named `get` if you choose). For example:

```
var o = Object.create({inherited: 1}, {
   foo: {
     value: {get: (function () { /* ... code ... */ })() }
   }
});
```

For more detailed information about the property descriptor object see: [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Answer (score 1):

`foo` corresponds to an object with one property, and that property is a function, as you say, but the second parameter of [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) is used to define properties. `o.foo` is one such property of the new object `o`. It defines a getter, so it isn't a "value property" but an "accessor property". Trying to read from `o.foo` causes the getter to be called.

As for

```
get: (function () { // a closure
      var closured = 'foo';
      return function () {
        return closured+'bar';
      };
})()
```

it returns a function, while

```
get: (function () { // a closure
      var closured = 'foo';
        return closured+'bar';
})()
```

returns the string `'foobar'`, so they aren't equivalent, but the first code block is equivalent to

```
get: function () { // a closure
      var closured = 'foo';
        return closured+'bar';
}
```

which returns a function, too. In the example, that closure is useless, but you could do

```
foo: (function() {
    var closured = 'foo';
    return {
        'get': function () {
            return closured+'bar';
        },
        'set': function (value) {
            closured = value;
        }
    };
})()
```

That way, both the getter and the setter would be able to access `closured`, but no other functions would:

```
console.log(o.foo); // "foobar"
o.foo = "a";
console.log(o.foo); // "abar"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you don't understand right about the code.

```
var o = Object.create({inherited: 1}, {
  foo: {
    get: function(){ return 1; }
  }
});

console.log(o.foo); // 1
o.foo = 5;
console.log(o.foo); // 1
```

The second parameter to `Object.create` describes the object's properties. In this case, the `get` part is actually a getter, so it describes what happens when the `foo` property of object `o` is read.

---

```
(function () { 
  var closure = 'foo';
  return function () {
    return 'bar';
  };
})()
```

This construct is called an IIFE. It is a function that is called immediately. The advantage of an IIFE is that it creates a local scope, so the `closure` variable is not visible in the outer scope. This avoids conflicts.

---

```
get: (function () { // a closure
  var closured = 'foo';
  return function () {
    return closured+'bar';
  };
})()
// versus:

get: function () { // changed it a bit to be a getter
  var closured = 'foo';
  return closured+'bar';
}
```

In the first case, the closured variable is outside of the getter function, while in the second it is inside. Being outside means that its state is not reset everytime the function(getter) is called and it can be available in other functions as well which would all share the same variable. Here is a potential use case:

```
var namespace = Object.create(null, {
  uniqueId : {
    get : (function(){
      var counter = 0;
      return function() {
        return counter++;
      };
    })()
  }
});

console.log(namespace.uniqueId); // 0
console.log(namespace.uniqueId); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to both your questions can be found on [this documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). If you read the part about properties you can see that the second argument for the Object.create function is not simply merged into the prototype but it is actually a definition of properties with getters, setters and various options.

With that in mind have a look at the code in:

```
get: (function () { // a closure
  var closured = 'foo';
  return function () {
    return closured+'bar';
  };
})()
```

As you said a self-invoking anonymous function is assigned to get. This function returns a function that closes over the closured variable and returns the closured+bar value. This is not equivalent to the following:

```
get: (function () { // a closure
  var closured = 'foo';
    return closured+'bar';
})()
```

The reason is that in this case to get is assigned an actual value and not a function, breaking the property specification that the Object.create expects.

Answer (score 0):

With `get` you define a `getter` method for the property with name `foo`. So each time you have a read access to `foo`, it will execute the getter method. That's why the immediately executed function itself returns a function (it is the resulting getter).

Executing `o.foo` will cause a read access to the `foo` property of `o`, so the getter will be executed.

Answer (score -1):

A closure is the ability to access variable outside of function. I think you have already knew it.

So now to the question of why doing

```
get: (function () { // a closure
  var closured = 'foo';
  return function () {
    return closured+'bar';
  };
})()
```

You see, when you do it this way, you can not only get "closured" variable, you can modify it!(although you did you modify it) Also 'closure' now will not be recycled. So it will live in the memory rather then clean up when function returns.